# Understanding Why we Integrate joint density function with opposite bounds to get marginal density

Tags: probability, density-function, marginal-probability

I have a function $f_{x,y}(x,y)$ which represents the joint density function. In order to get marginal density function in terms of $x$, I need to integrate using $y$ bounds. Why is that? I assumed that we would integrate with $x$ bounds.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! While your particular question is clear as is, since you do not require many equations, it is considered good practice to use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for their readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For intuition it is often good practice to use discrete probabilities instead of continuous densities. Integrating is just a form of summation. Now if you had the following matrix

|  | sick | healthy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test positive | 0.09 | 0.1 |
| Test negative | 0.01 | 0.8 |

then getting the probability of someone being sick ($X\in\{\text{sick},\text{healthy}\}$) requires summing over the different test cases ($Y\in\{\text{positive},\text{negative}\}$)
$$
P_X(\text{sick}) = \sum_{y\in\{\text{positive},\text{negative}\}} P_{X,Y}(\text{sick}, y) = 0.09 + 0.01 = 0.1.
$$
More generally we have
$$
P_X(x) = \sum_{y\in\{\text{positive},\text{negative}\}} P_{X,Y}(x, y),
$$
which works the same for densities
$$
f_X(x) = \int f_{X,Y}(x,y) dy
$$

Comment: That clears up a lot of things, thank you!